# Flex sorting of XMLListCollection subelements

Tags: xml, apache-flex, list, sorting, collections

In a Flex webapp, is there an easy way to go about applying a sort to the children of an XML element, based on the children's attributes? Example follows below:

XMLListCollection:

> `<a anotherProp="ABCDE">`
>       `<e prop="AB">1</element>`
>      `<e prop="BC">2</element>`
>    `</a>`
>    `<a anotherProp="FGEH">`
>       `<e prop="HF">3</element>`
>       `<e prop="AD">4</element>`
>       `<e prop="AC">5</element>`
>    `</a>`

I would like to sort the `<e>` elements, within each `<a>` element separately, according to their "prop" attribute. My code for generating the array containing the `<a>` elements is along the lines of:

```
for each(var node:XML in initialInput:XMLListCollection){
  if(node.localName()=="a"){
    //I was hoping to be able to sort the <e> children of the node variable here
    xmlListCollectionVar.addItem(node);
  }
}
```

At the end I would like the `<a>`'s to remain in their defined order, but their `<e>` children to be sorted based on the "prop" attribute. So far if I try:

> node.children().sort=someSortVar

where someSortVar has its fields set to:

> SortFields("e.@prop",...)

I get an exception about a null value. Any way to convert the children list to XMLListCollection, sort it and integrate it back into the node variable? Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Solved by finding code on the Adobe Flex forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two solutions:  The first involved converting an XMLList to an array and sorting on the array:

```
  for each (var a:XML in elt..a)
  {
    var children:Array = toArray(a.children());
    children.sortOn("@prop");
    a.setChildren(new XMLList());
    for each (var c:XML in children)
    {
      a.appendChild(c);
    }
  }
```

The second involved using the sort attribute of an `XMLListCollection`, although I believe that the <a> children are an `XMLList`, not an `XMLListCollection`:

```
  var sort:Sort = new Sort()
  sort.fields = [new SortField("@prop")];
  for each (var a:XML in xml..a)
  {
    var xcoll:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(a.children());
    xcoll.sort = sort;
    xcoll.refresh();
    a.setChildren(xcoll.copy());
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution - the links from the Adobe forums contained solutions along these lines also, but had a bit of overhead in terms of helper functions and whatnot so I think I'll go with your approach involving XMLListCollection.

Comment: I cannot edit your post but you forgot xcol1.refresh(); in the XMLListCollection approach. Just a note to anyone who happens to come across this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [sort](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#sort()) function on the array with a compareFunction.

> ... args — The arguments specifying a
>   comparison function and one or more
>   values that determine the behavior of
>   the sort. This method uses the syntax
>   and argument order
>   **Array.sort(compareFunction,
>   sortOptions)** with the arguments
>   defined as follows:
>
> **compareFunction** - A comparison
>   function used to determine the sorting
>   order of elements in an array. This
>   argument is optional. A comparison
>   function should take two arguments to
>   compare. Given the elements A and B,
>   the result of compareFunction can have
>   one of the following three values:
>   -1, if A should appear before B in the sorted sequence 0, if A equals B 1, if
>   A should appear after B in the sorted
>   sequence sortOptions - One or more
>   numbers or defined constants,
>   separated by the | (bitwise OR)
>   operator, that change the behavior of
>   the sort from the default. This
>   argument is optional. The following
>   values are acceptable for sortOptions:
>   1 or Array.CASEINSENSITIVE 2 or
>   Array.DESCENDING 4 or Array.UNIQUESORT
>   8 or Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY 16 or
>   Array.NUMERIC For more information,
>   see the Array.sortOn() method.

Comment: Sorry - edited title and code - I'm actually using XMLListCollection not an Array. The XML example in my post would be this XMLListCollection (<a><e></e>...</a>).

Answer (score 0):

Found suitable code implementations on the Adobe forums - sorry about not looking there first.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/72521#72521

Comment: Another link for a different code implementation is http://forums.adobe.com/message/1950215#1950215