# Sorting XMLListCollection

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have been trying to sort an XMLListCollection following instructions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272038/flex-sorting-of-xmllistcollection-subelements) for some time, without success. Here's the relevant code:

```
<fx:Declarations>
<s:HTTPService id="photoServ" url="pics.xml" resultFormat="e4x"/>
<s:XMLListCollection id="photoList" source = "{photoServ.lastResult.photo}"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List id="imageList" dataProvider="{photoList}" />
```

My goal is to sort the following xml file by location instead of using the entire `XMLListCollection` as the List's `dataProvider`, based on an input variable of the location.

*Pics.XML*

```
<photos>
<photo title="Picture 1" location="Canada" medium="Photograph" thumb="images/thumbs/Picture1.png" image="images/Picture1.png"/>
<photo title="Picture 2" location="UK" medium="Photograph" thumb="images/thumbs/Picture2.png" image="images/Picture2.png"/>
<photo title="Picture 3" location="USA" medium="Photograph" thumb="images/thumbs/Picture3.png" image="images/Picture3.png"/>
<photo title="Picture 4" location="Canada" medium="Photograph" thumb="images/thumbs/Picture4.png" image="images/Picture4.png"/>
<photo title="Picture 5" location="USA" medium="Photograph" thumb="images/thumbs/Picture5.png" image="images/Picture5.png"/>
<photo title="Picture 6" location="UK" medium="Photograph" thumb="images/thumbs/Picture6.png" image="images/Picture6.png"/>
</photos>
```

Any and all help is appreciated to get this sorted.

**EDIT**

THis is for a photogallery, and I want to be able to show images based on location - in this case Canada, USA, UK, etc. THanks for the input!

Comment: I'm not sure if you really want to sort it, or if you want to filter it. If the former, use a sortFunction, or if the latter, use a filterFunction.

Comment: Good point - I just want to _filter_ it based on location and that's it - so I can input location with a variable and all of Canada, UK, or USA show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do

```
photoList.(@location=="Canada" || @location=="USA");
```

to get a list of `<photo>` tags with the location as Canada or USA

On second thought, you would want to set the xmlListCollection as

```
photoList=new XMLListCollection(photoServ.lastResult.photo.(@location=="Canada" || @location=="USA"));
```

**EDIT**

To add code for different locations, lets assume you have a `DropDownList` already populated with the location array. Assuming your locations array will be like

```
var locs:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(["USA", "UK", "Canada", /*and others too*/]);
```

and your `DropDownList` (lets call it `locationList`) has its `dataProvider` as `locs`

Now, when you want to filter on the location, all you need to do is

```
var lns:Vector.<Object>=locationList.selectedItems;
var filtered:XMLList=photoServ.lastResult.photo.(lns.indexOf(@location) != -1);
var photoList=new XMLListCollection(filtered);
```

Comment: That throws a 1123 error, until I go `photoList.source.(@location=="Canada")` But it fails as my `imageList` dataProvider. I tried populating a new `XMLList` with the line you suggest, and use it as the source of another `XMLListCollection` to use as the dataProvider for my list - but it contains no data.

Comment: ahh, I saw the new suggestion. It's giving me a type coercion error from `XMLList` to `XMLListCollection`

Comment: `PhotoList.source = photoServ...` gives me a `#1065: Variable location is not defined` error

Comment: and randomly it started to work - same code. Thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: But i'm having trouble adding a variable instead of "Canada" and "UK", etc, it's giving me that 1065 when I try to implement it in the equation.

Comment: it seems to go in and out of working between recognizing different properties with `@property` (ie, medium, location, etc) and offering 1065s. Is this a common problem?

Comment: No It isn't. You need to create a new `XMLListCollection` like I've changed in my answer now. I've also added code to search on different location attributes.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayCollection and XMLListCollection behave in a very similar manner. XMLListCollection have properties filterfunction and sort, using which filtering and sorting the collection can be easy.

```
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.SortField;
            import mx.collections.Sort;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var _photoXML:XML =
                        <photos>
                            <photo title="Picture 1" location="Canada" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture1.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture1.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 2" location="UK" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture2.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture2.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 3" location="USA" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture3.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture3.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 4" location="Canada" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture4.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture4.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 5" location="USA" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture5.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture5.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 6" location="UK" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture6.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture6.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 7" location="Canada" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture2.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture1.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 8" location="UK" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture3.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture2.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 9" location="Canada" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture6.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture4.jpg"/>
                            <photo title="Picture 10" location="UK" medium="Photograph" thumb="assets/images/thumbs/Picture4.jpg" image="assets/images/Picture6.jpg"/>
                        </photos> ;

            [Bindable] 
            private var _countryCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(["select country","USA", "UK", "Canada"])

            private function filterByLocation(event:Event):void {
                if(countryCollection.selectedIndex > 0){
                    photoList.filterFunction = filter_ByLocation;
                    photoList.refresh();
                }else{
                    photoList.filterFunction = null;
                    photoList.refresh();
                }
            }

            private function filter_ByLocation(item:XML):Boolean {
                return item.@location == countryCollection.selectedItem;
            }

            private function sortByTitle():void {
                var titleSort:Sort = new Sort();
                    titleSort.fields = [new SortField('@location', true)];

                photoList.sort = titleSort;
                photoList.refresh();
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:XMLListCollection id="photoList" source="{_photoXML.children()}"/>

    <mx:VBox width="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
        <mx:Image source="{imageList.selectedItem.@image}" width="800" height="400"/>
        <mx:HorizontalList id="imageList" dataProvider="{photoList}" labelField="@thumb" width="100%" height="100"
                           columnWidth="130" rowHeight="100" creationComplete="sortByTitle();">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Image source="{data.@thumb}"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:HorizontalList>    
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:ComboBox id="countryCollection" dataProvider="{_countryCollection}" change="filterByLocation(event)"/>
</mx:Application>
```